# Conversion error while using datediff in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datediff

So basically, I'm having this error:
[Error image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KirCf.png)

Normally I would accept that my code is wrong and fix it, but the thing is it appears to be working most of the time. And I can't find the difference between cases. Why is **'04-09-2018'** working fine as a date but **'17-08-2019'** is being taken as a String?

This code takes the date from a cell in a datagridview where the date is temporary stored using a format from a database:

```
Private Sub wrty_show()
    Dim dt As Date : Dim difd As String
    dt = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
    difd = DateDiff("d", dt, Today)
    If (difd >= 365) Then : Label11.Text = "Invalid" : Label11.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    ElseIf (difd < 365) Then : Label11.Text = "Valid" : Label11.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is part of the query I use to retrieve the date from my database into the datagridview cell, with the special format to show (Somehow I get the idea that this turns the Date into a String but I'm not 100% sure because I don't have that much experience working with dates):

```
DATE_FORMAT(w.wrty_date , '%d-%m-%Y') AS wrty_date
```

I know that the format is related to the error, because I tested the program without it and it worked just fine. But the format is necessary, and if it would be the main cause that would just make **every** Item end up in an Error not just some of them.
I figured some workaround myself of course, but I wanna know why the error is not definitive and shows up sometimes, and since it's my first question here I don't know many of the rules yet, so I apologize for anything out of place or lack of proper information. If I'm missing something please tell me and I'll update the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is '04-09-2018' working fine as a date but '17-08-2019' is being
>   taken as a String?

Because the date format of current thread culture is running as "mm-dd-yyyy" so when you try to assing "04-09-2018" the system is able to convert it in 9th April 2018, but when you try to assign "17-08-2019" system is not able to convert it to date.

Try the below code

```
   Private Sub wrty_show()
      Dim dt As Date : Dim difd As String
      dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
      difd = DateDiff("d", dt, Today)
      If (difd >= 365) Then : Label11.Text = "Invalid" : Label11.ForeColor = 
         System.Drawing.Color.Red
      ElseIf (difd < 365) Then : Label11.Text = "Valid" : Label11.ForeColor = 
         System.Drawing.Color.Green
      End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: I would never guess the problem was between day and month, Thank you.